# Apache2: create a unique identifier that is actually base64 encoded

Tags: apache

Apache has a module called [mod_unique_id](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unique_id.html) that generates a unique environment variable (`UNIQUE_ID`) that is unique across all requests. However, its encoding is over the range `[A-Za-z0-9@-]` instead of the usual base64 `[A-Za-z0-9+/]`.

I would like an environment variable that is unique across all requests that is *actually* base64 encoded (or at least, to some subset of base64 like hexadecimal).

If I try to create such an environment variable like so:

```
Define myid "expr=%{base64:UNIQUE_ID}"
SetEnv MYID "%{myid}"
```

Then `MYID` has a value that is not regenerated on every new request.

So, my question is this: Can I manipulate `UNIQUE_ID` so that it is actually base 64, or else can I create an environment variable that is unique to all requests to the server.

Comment: Why would you want it to be 64 (24bits) rather than 144bits?

Comment: The Content-Security-Policy response header allows you to specify a nonce to the script-src directive. It should be base64 encoded if I remember correctly (although I can't seem to find that written anywhere right now...). UNIQUE_ID may be composed of characters that are invalid in that directive (namely @ and -) so using it as is will not work. Basically I am trying to hack MediaWiki to add a nonce attribute to its inline script tags so I can enforce a CSP.

Comment: I'm surprised that `expr=%{base64:UNIQUE_ID}` won't give you an new value on every request... Have you tried `expr=%{base64:UNIQUE_ID}`?
Do you get a entirely static value?
For mediawiki you could also register a [auto prepend php file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) that sets the environment variable.

Comment: @xsrf:I checked again and the problem appears to be `expr=%{base64:UNIQUE_ID}`: what this produces is literally "UNIQUE_ID" converted to base 64 -- it has not substituted the value of the variable `%UNIQUE_ID`. I don't why this should be since I've followed https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** In case you missed it, in order to use `expr=...` you need Apache 2.4.10 or later as noted in the "Compatability" line/section of the [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#RequestHeader) page.

Having clarified that, it still did not work for me using `Define ...`.  What worked for me was to add a `RequestHeader ...` line in httpd.conf (at the global level).  The key is to call `reqenv(UNIQUE_ID)` as the argument to `base64()`:

```
...
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

# add the following line
RequestHeader set X-Nonce "expr=%{base64:%{reqenv:UNIQUE_ID}}"
...
```

Restart apache (in CentOS 7, this would be):

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Then from php you can get it via:

```
$r = apache_request_headers();
echo $r['X-Nonce'];
```

Alternatively, you can also extract it via `$_SERVER`:

```
# notice that it is all in caps with the 'HTTP_' prefix
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_NONCE'];
```