# Convert Base64 in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

My Line is as under in .htaccess

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e'; style-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e';"
```

Please let me know how to convert `%{UNIQUE_ID}e` into base64 value in .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Apache 2.4.10+ then you can use Apache expressions in the *value* argument of the `Header` directive. This gives you access to a `base64` function that can be used to base 64 encode the `UNIQUE_ID` environment variable.

For example (untested):

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "expr=script-src 'self' 'nonce-%{base64:%{reqenv:UNIQUE_ID}}'; style-src 'self' 'nonce-%{base64:%{reqenv:UNIQUE_ID}}';"
```

See also the following question which actually appears to have the same end goal (after reading the comments), although the suggested solution requires access to the server config (and PHP), which may be undesirable:

- [Apache2: create a unique identifier that is actually base64 encoded](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/116285/apache2-create-a-unique-identifier-that-is-actually-base64-encoded)

The following [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21108456/369434) also offers a solution that uses a server-side `RewriteMap` and an external program to do the base64 conversion. This would work on Apache 2.2 and earlier, but does require server access.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032461/how-to-base64-encode-apache-header